# How to use html2canvas with jsPDF using angular2

Tags: css, angular, typescript, jspdf, html2canvas

I want to generate a page pdf with css and images as it shown in my navigator.

I don't know which way to combine between jsPDF and html2canvas.

I'm trying this but it gives me a blank page:
**document.ts**

```
declare let jsPDF;
declare let html2canvas;
var doc = new jsPDF();
html2canvas(document.getElementById('content'), {

    onrendered: function (canvas) {

        doc.addHTML(canvas, 15, 15 );
    }
});
doc.output("dataurlnewwindow");
```

these two scripts are in index.html

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.0.272/jspdf.debug.js"></script><!--// to use jsPDF for registring pdf file-->
<script src="/sJs/html2canvas.js"></script>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do ? It's not very clear from your question. Also your code is mixing typescript, javascript and HTML..

Comment: I want generate pdf file with keeping my css style